# Kotlin generic trying to infer wrong ype

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

```
private inline fun <reified T> deserializeRequest(data: String): T? {
    return try {
        jsonParser.fromJson(data, T::class.java)
    } catch (e: JsonSyntaxException) {
        log()
        null
    }
}
```

I get an error on `jsonParser.fromJson`, It complains about type mismatch, expects T but found Int

Any idea why?

Comment: If we can see your `exception` and `data` it may be helpful to figure it out.

Comment: What's the exact message of the type mismatch error?

Comment: there is no exception, it's a compile error saying that it's expecting T but it found Int. If you just copy that into android studio it'll give compile error

Comment: @aryaxt it doesn't give any compile error in Android Studio. It works perfectly. I am using 3.1 version.